# AWS, WordPress and URL issue

Tags: wordpress, amazon-aws, amazon-ec2

We set up WordPress and the website works okay but when a visitor clicks on any link the URL doesn't change. As far as I can tell we're using EC2. I've tried a few different themes and the issue remains.

For example, say we have the URL example.com. When a visitor clicks on the link to the blog, the URL should change to example.com/blog but it stays example.com. It does that no matter what link you click on.

I want the URL to change along with the permalinks (not sure if that's the right phrasing), so when you click on a link, the correct URL is displayed. Any suggestions? In the meantime, I'll try other WordPress themes as well. Thanks

Comment: The URL isn't changing? But does the site work?

Comment: That's correct, @JohnConde.

Comment: was any answer helpful? I'm interested in how you solved this

Comment: Still looking for more detail.

Comment: Are you using a browser like Safari that hides the url except for the domain until you actually click into the URL bar?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have access to ftp .... If so I will suggest you to delete all files and Important Delete .htaccess and then reinstall Wordpress with your theme .... I had this kind of problem and .htaccess was the issue ... But in some cases , some thing goes wrong with Wordpress installation and you might get his issue

Answer (score 1):

The pages are changing, however you don't see the url change as it's really just that single frame changing.

Another way to do a similar interaction is via AJAX. Which is a mixture of things, pretty much the site makes a call to the server for the new page and through JavaScript the page rerenders what it is told to. For switching pages this is completely unnecessary unless you have something like an messaging system on the bottom. And if AJAX is being used you should still have a regular version of the site for users without JavaScript or for users that link to open links in a new Tab\Window.

If you right click and open in a new tab\window you'll see the actual page you are going to, (e.g. http://www.example.com/new/ )It would be better to link directly to that page instead of inside the frames.

There's one reason for that - bookmarking. If a page is in a frame, when you bookmark it you can only bookmark the framed page, not the pages inside. This makes usability for the end user hindered with zero benefits. Another aspect, frames and search engines don't always get along which can leave many pages on your site from being indexed properly.

Comment: Do you have a solution for WordPress and/or more details into fixing this?